# Proof that distribution has power law tails from having infinite moments

Tags: probability, statistics

Is the fact that the 2nd (or higher) moment of a distribution is infinite (while, say,the first moment is finite) proof that the distribution has power law tails?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is N here?

Comment: NARQ, sorry. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Modified. My question is if 1rst moment finite and higher ones infinite, is it proof of power law tail?

Comment: @Nero what do you mean by power law tails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $E[|X|^\alpha]$ is finite then $P[|X|\geqslant x]=o(1/x^\alpha)$ when $x\to\infty$. The reverse implication is not true.

If $E[|X|]$ is finite and $E[|X|^\alpha]$ is infinite for some $\alpha\gt1$, then one can say that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}xP[|X|\geqslant x]=0$ and that $\limsup\limits_{x\to\infty}x^\beta P[|X|\geqslant x]\ne0$ for some $\beta\gt1$.

Comment: The idea is whether $E[X]$ finite and $E[X^2]$ infinite implies that, for x large enough, $P[X\geq x]$ approaches $K x^{-\alpha}$ where K is a normalizing constant and  $\alpha \in (1,2)$.

Comment: The idea is that my answer states what this implies and omits what this does not imply. One can easy construct counterexamples to the result in your comment, for example where $(\log P(X\geqslant x))/\log x$ oscillates, hence diverges.

Comment: Thanks; do you have a good reference?

Comment: Sorry but I find difficult to understand the kind of approach you are interested in: do you strive for maths results or what? If you do not, why bother posting on a maths forum?

Comment: I got the answer,thank you, I crave math results,  and I was wondering if there is work on that, or neighboring points in the literature.

Comment: I meant I got the answer from the 2 comments here, that infinite $n^{th}$ moment doesn't necessarily imply power laws  and I thanked you.

Answer (score 1):

I see we have here a discussion between a mathematician, detail oriented for exactness of the result and a physicist who has a global vision, but no idea of the zoology of ackward distributions a mathematician is able work out...
Let us state a precise mathemtical question: assume that a distribution has finite moments until a given degree m, then infinite for alpha > m (the case of alpha = m exactly can be finite or infinite). Assume also that the pdf f(x) is decreasing at infinity, in order to avoid oscillations. We also assume that the distribution is one-sided (support in IR+) in order to avoid compensation effects between the two sides. Then is there an exponent m' and a constant k such that f(x) > k x^-m' for any x ?
This would be an interesting mathematical exercise ! My guess is that the answer is still negative, though the general idea is very much valid.